# How to check if current time format is 12h

Tags: linux, terminal

On Ubuntu , i can set time format use GUI(12h or 24h).
Then, i want to check this setting use terminal, how to do it.
Somebody help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...requires a different command:

12-hour:

```
dconf write /org/mate/panel/objects/clock/prefs/format "'12-hour'"
```

and, as one would expect, 24-hour:

```
 dconf write /org/mate/panel/objects/clock/prefs/format "'24-hour'"
```

I think this will do okay to check the time

```
 $ date
```

to check the date

```
 # timedatectl or # timedatectl  status
```

To check CMOS Time

```
  # hwclock   # hwclock –systohc
```

Comment: He stated he knows how to change it. He needs to know how to check it.

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much ! i used dconf to read clock-format